# Calculate the combinations of different numbers which in sum give 42

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a temporary table “Number_game” with 2 columns: Digit_number and Letter_number. Insert the values in the table from 1 (one) to 20 (twenty).

How I calculate the combinations of different numbers which in sum give 42?

```
 Select nb.Digit_number, ng.Digit_number
 from #Number_game as nb
 join #Number_game as ng on nb.Digit_number = ng.Digit_number
 where nb.Digit_number + ng.Digit_number =42;
```

I don't know how to take more values to have 42 in sum...

Here is the data I have inserted:

```
 INSERT INTO #Number_game(Digit_number, Letter_number)
Values (1,'one'),
(2,'two'),
(3,'three'),
(4,'four'),
(5,'five'),
(6,'six'),
(7,'seven'),
(8,'eight'),
(9,'nine'),
(10,'ten'),
(11,'eleven'),
(12,'twelve'),
(13,'thirteen'),
(14,'fourteen'),
(15,'fifteen'),
(16,'sixteen'),
(17,'seventeen'),
(18,'eighteen'),
(19,'nineteen'),
(20,'twenty');
```

Comment: You can take more than 2 numbers. I need combinations of different numbers.

Comment: Please post your effort

Comment: Are you asking for the maths, a query or both?  This is a task which is better suited to other languages (C#, Java, etc).

Comment: I ask for a query...

Comment: Add sample data and expected output

Comment: Output doesn`t matter...

Comment: I think query will not give you output like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `CROSS JOIN`

```
With CTE as
(
select a1.digitnumber as n1, 
       a2.digitnumber as n2, 
       a3.digitnumber as n3
from number_game a1
cross join number_game a2
cross join number_game a3
)
select *
from CTE
where n1 + n2 + n3 = 42
```

Comment: but i think he need every combination of this value

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.